# How can I make repeated calls to an async method with an on/off switch

Tags: c#

In a WinForm application, I have an On/Off switch for a background process.
On Click, the program launch a process and restart it when it's finish, till you use the Off switch.

The following code is the working attempt that had multiple issues.

From Damien_The_Unbeliever comments:
suspend threads which means that they stay around forever, and implementing looping via recursion which could easily cause a stack overflow.

```
public partial class frmMain
{
    Thread thread;
    bool isRunning = false;

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnOffSwitch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isRunning)
        {
            btnSwitch.Text = "Stop";
            isRunning = true;

            thread = new Thread(doLoop);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            if (thread.IsAlive)
                thread.Suspend();

            btnSwitch.Text = "Start";
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }

    public void doLoop()
    {
        ClearScreenLogic.Run();

        if (AutoReconnect)
            ReconnectLogic.Run();
        // Etc..

        doLoop();
    }
```

I am trying to switch from this working solution to [background worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @PeterBons, How to make repetitive call of an async method with a on/off switch?

Comment: Two major issues - you suspend threads which means that they stay around forever, and you're implementing looping via recursion which could easily cause a stack overflow. Not sure what your current problem is though.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is the "make it work" part I didn't knew how to properly code it so I did this ugly patch. The problem is I want to implement a proper an clean way of this repetitive call.

Comment: Thats exactly what my comment in the original code were about. If this is unclear, show no effort of doing it himself, or asking us for code. Please tell me. I provided a little exemple of what Im trying to achieve, and how I'm currently doing it. I did not provide a not working try, because it would have been confusing and would have been close for typo or Something like this as a X/Y issue.

Comment: why you didn't use a while loop inside your `doLoop()`with a flag to cancel it? your current code has also another issue: you Suspend the thread and create a new Thread instead of Resume!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your doLoop in the [`DoWork`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the BackGroundWorker and make sure you handle cancelation. Make sure to set the properties of your backgroundworker to WorkerReportprogress and WorkerSupportCancellation to true;

This is what you would need:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // on and off
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        // cancel if we have not already done so
        if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // start the background work
        button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

// this runs on a background thread
// do not do stuff with the UI here
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int progress = 0;
    // stop looping if cancellation is requested
    while (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
    {
        // make it nice
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress);

        ClearScreenLogic.Run();

        if (AutoReconnect)
            ReconnectLogic.Run();
        // Etc..

        progress++; // for feedback
    }
}

// tell the use something is going on, this runs on the UI thread
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
}

// we're done, tell the user so
// this runs on the UI thread 
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    label1.Text = "cancelled";
}
```

When implemented correctly your users will see something like this:

[image]